# Node- soap request - Setting preemptive authorization

Tags: node.js, soap, authorization

I'm new at soap requests, and after setting username and pwd, I also need to set preemptive option. To true or setting the type. I reealy want o know how to set this option since that resolved my request problem in soapUi tool.

code on Angular:
client.setEndpoint(this.apiUrlSoap);
client.addHttpHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('user:pwd'));

I search a lot for this and couldn't find any answer.

Thank you

I tried this:
client.addHttpHeader('Authentication Type', 'Preemptive') ??? Not this for sure...

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I've tried another aproach but still didn't work...

```
client.addHttpHeader("httpclient.authentication.preemptive", "true");
client.addHttpHeader("Authentication-Type", "Preemptive");
```

Result in Request Headers:

```
Authentication-Type: Preemptive
Authorization: Bearer 
httpclient.authentication.preemptive: true
```

The status code is 200 ok, but in preview I only see the user and password inputs. I just want to pass that...